# How to configure the widget Entry so that the length of the frame so as not to exceed 11 characters

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I am on Ubuntu 20.04. I need to configure the frame of `GTK::Entry` widget to not exceed 11 characters. I thought I could use this code `set_max_width_chars`

```
Gtk::Entry nomUsb;
nomUsb.set_can_focus(true);
nomUsb.set_max_length(11);
nomUsb.set_max_width_chars(11);
boiteBoutonsH1.pack_start(nomUsb, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
```

but the result gives this (20 characters):

[image]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that will, I suspect, do what you want:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{

public:

    MainWindow()
    {
        // Can't type in more than 11 chars (copy/paste will truncate):
        m_11CharMax.set_max_length(11);

        // Sets the width of the entry to about 11 characters wide (depends on the character):
        m_11CharMax.set_width_chars(11);
    
        add(m_11CharMax);
        show_all();
    }

private:

    Gtk::Entry m_11CharMax;

};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "so.question.q63568716");
    
    MainWindow w;

    return app->run(w);
}
```

The following Makefile will build this for you (assuming the code is in a file named `main.cpp`:

```
all: main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp -o example.out `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

The program `example.out` will create a window with a `Gtk::Entry` as its sole child widget. This entry will be *about* 11 characters wide (note that this depends on the character. For example, `m` is larger than `l` in the UI's font). Also, it will not accept more than 11 characters as input:

[image]

If you try to copy and paste more that 11 characters to it, the entry will automatically truncate it to fit. Even if you resize it, you will not be able to feed it more that 11 characters:

[image]